# What does "Earthly knowledge is but shadow" mean?

Tags: meaning, quotations

What does "Earthly knowledge is but shadow" mean? It is a quote from the famous philosopher Plato.

Comment: Is this a question about English language?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philosophy, and probably belongs on the [Philosophy.se] stack.

Comment: but it's about english

Comment: @Bobthezealot it is _in_ English, but you can see (from the answer) that it's _about_ philosophy. Sometimes you don't know you're posting in the wrong stack until you do, though, and that's why it may be migrated to a different stack, in this case [Philosophy.se].

Comment: I think this *could* be about English, but a little more work needs to be put into it before it's primarily an English question. For example, one could ask "What is _earthly knowledge_? Surely Plato isn't talking about geology, is he?" Or, "I'm having trouble grasping the meaning of _but shadow_. I looked up _shadow_ in the dictionary, and the closest meaning I could find was 'sadness', but I think I might be missing something." Such clarifications would make this an ELL question, so long as, before asking here, the O.P. did some good faith research in an honest effort find an answer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a metaphor drawn from ‘Allegory of the Cave’ in Plato's *Republic*. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave) describes the passage thus:

> Plato has Socrates describe a gathering of people who have lived chained to the wall of a cave all of their lives, facing a blank wall. The people watch shadows projected on the wall by things passing in front of a fire behind them, and begin to designate names to these shadows. The shadows are as close as the prisoners get to viewing reality. He then explains how the philosopher is like a prisoner who is freed from the cave and comes to understand that the shadows on the wall do not make up reality at all, as he can perceive the true form of reality rather than the mere shadows seen by the prisoners.

That is, what we perceive through the senses is merely a shadow of the true Forms which lie in a realm beyond sensual perception, accessible only to Reason.